# unresolved external symbol while loading HDF5 library via vcpkg to C++ vscode project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg

I am using visual studio project 2019- and vcpkg in order to load data to CUDA 11.6 C++ visual studio  project.
at the begining of the file i have :

```
// #define H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB 
#include <H5Cpp.h>
```

and it do not give any errors - so I assume it was correctly loaded and integrated by by vcpkg. Also as visible at the end of the post H5 files are visible in external dependencies list of a solution explorer.

simple code that leads to error is shown below

```
    H5::H5File file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
    H5::DataSet dset = file.openDataSet(DATASET_NAME);
```

error (set of unresolved external symbol errors) - it appears in compile time.
[image]

If I will uncomment #define H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB 1 the error discussed above disappears but new shows (in runtime) -

```
hdf5_cpp_D.dll not found ...
```

Exactly the same code worked perfectly well on my cmake CUDA C++ project, but for various reasons I need to switch to visual studio project.

Minimal example giving error

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
//#define H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB 1
#include <H5Cpp.h>
#include <stdio.h>





void loadHDFIntoBoolArr(H5std_string FILE_NAME, H5std_string DATASET_NAME, bool*& data) {


    H5::H5File file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
    H5::DataSet dset = file.openDataSet(DATASET_NAME);
    /*
     * Get the class of the datatype that is used by the dataset.
     */
    H5T_class_t type_class = dset.getTypeClass();
    H5::DataSpace dspace = dset.getSpace();
    int rank = dspace.getSimpleExtentNdims();


    hsize_t dims[2];
    rank = dspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dims, NULL); // rank = 1
    printf("Datasize: %d \n ", dims[0]); // this is the correct number of values

     // Define the memory dataspace
    hsize_t dimsm[1];
    dimsm[0] = dims[0];
    H5::DataSpace memspace(1, dimsm);

    data = (bool*)calloc(dims[0], sizeof(bool));

    dset.read(data, H5::PredType::NATIVE_HBOOL, memspace, dspace);

    file.close();

}

void loadHDF() {
    const int WIDTH = 512;
    const int HEIGHT = 512;
    const int DEPTH = 826;


    const H5std_string FILE_NAMEonlyLungsBoolFlat("C:\\Users\\1\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject3\\mytestfile.hdf5");
    const H5std_string DATASET_NAMEonlyLungsBoolFlat("onlyLungsBoolFlat");
    // create a vector the same size as the dataset
    bool* onlyLungsBoolFlat;
    loadHDFIntoBoolArr(FILE_NAMEonlyLungsBoolFlat, DATASET_NAMEonlyLungsBoolFlat, onlyLungsBoolFlat);

  

}


int main()
{
    loadHDF();
    return 0;
}
```

vcpk commands used

```
.\vcpkg install hdf5
.\vcpkg install hdf5[cpp]
.\vcpkg integrate install
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778873/visual-studio-2019-win10-and-hdf5-installed-using-vcpkg-unresolved-external-s ? Please show a [mre] including how you installed the library and the full error messages

Comment: thank You I am now uploading mimal working example of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my situation was simple just reinstall windows - on fresh installation I did steps as mentioned at the begining and all works now

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: I am trying but for now I do not see such option will look one more time later

Answer (score 4):

If you build this with `H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB 1` defined, there should be the `hdf5_cpp_D.dll` lying around under the `vcpkg_installed` directory somewhere. Look at $(vcpkg_root)\installed\ and search for a hdf5 directory. There should be a `.\bin` and a `.\debug\bin` directory there with `hdf5_cpp.dll` and `hdf5_cpp_D.dll`. (I am guessing that `_D` is for debug).

Normally `vcpkg integrate install` will set up Visual Studio so that the dlls from the vcpkg directory will be copied to your output directory automatically. But this may fail if the `hdf5` DLL is loaded dynamically at runtime. You will have to copy it manually (or add the path to the PATH environment variable).

---

If you build this without `H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB 1` defined, the symbols really should be defined in the static lib (`hdf5.lib`). Search for them in the `$(vcpkg)\installed` directory. There should be two (or four) different ones, one for release and one for debug (and each one for static vs. dll).

Oh, I forgot: Which vcpkg triplet are you using? That may also play a role into which `hdf5.lib` will be linked.

If you still get the linker error (undefined symbols), then perhaps the vcpkg port of hdf5 is not meant to be used with static linking. You should open a ticket then with hdf5.

---